# What are some subtle examples of the difference between necessity and sufficiency?

Tags: necessary-and-sufficient-conditions

What are some subtle examples of how the difference between these two things can greatly impact the meaning of a sentence, discussion, or conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

The standard example for the difference between *necessity* and *sufficiency* is "the rain, the sprinkling truck and the wet street":

Raining is *sufficient* that the street is wet. But raining is *not* *necessary* that the street is wet. Because operating of the sprinkling truck in the dry season is also sufficient for the street to be wet.

**Aside**:  Why do you ask this question? You have just edited a similar question [necessary versus sufficient](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/22/what-is-the-difference-between-necessary-and-sufficient?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Typing one's answer is necessary to respond to a question on this site, but it is not sufficient- the 'Post Your Answer' button must be clicked too.

As for subtleties, I wonder how long it will be before someone points out that typing isn't necessary because you can ask Alexa to do it!